# How to prevent needless re-rendering of stateless functions?

Tags: reactjs

I know it's a good practice to use as many stateless functions as possible, but I'm running into an issue where a parent container component renders, which of course will cause a cascade re-render of its children. Stateless functions have no way (as far as I know) of choosing not to render.

How should I optimize my application as far as renders, and still use stateless functions?

Comment: >> Stateless functions have no way (as far as I know) of choosing not to render.
Could you point to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a higher order function:

```
function once(fn) {
  let called = false;
  let result = null;
  return function() {
    if(!called) {
      called = true;
      result = fn.apply(null, arguments);
    }
    return result;
  };
}

const DumbComponent = once(() => {
  console.log("Rendering dumb component"); // will only ever happen once
  return (<div>I am a component</div>);
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/dMNKXJ?editors=0010)